# Will "LIMIT 1" improve performance of a SELECT INTO query in plpgsql

Tags: performance, postgresql, select, plpgsql

The Postgres 9 docs state:

> 38.5.3. Executing a Query with a Single-Row Result
>   SELECT
>   select_expressions INTO [STRICT] target FROM
>   ...; ....(doc'd othe details)...
>
> then target will be set to the first row returned by the query....
>   Any result rows after the first row are discarded.

My question is: are the rows discarded or is there really an implicit `LIMIT 1`?

So, `LIMIT 1` would not improve the performance of `SELECT INTO` returning many rows, or would it?

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT INTO` reads exactly one or two rows (with the `STRICT` option). So `LIMIT` is useless.

Answer (score -1):

From what I know using an ORDER BY and a LIMIT can often prevent *shortening* the query as it still needs to find all rows to perform the order by before it limits.
-Chris Shoemaker